# AngularJS pagination and Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination, slice

Iv'e got an problem.
Please help me what is wrong.

There is my code :

```
(function () {

    var app = angular.module('store', ['ui.bootstrap']);

    app.controller('StoreController', function ($scope, $http) {
        $scope.pageSize = 20;
        $scope.currentPage = 1;
        $http.get("../scripts/products.php").success(function (data) {
            $scope.products = data;
        });

    }).filter('startFrom', function () {
        return function (data, start) {
            return data.slice(start);
        };
    });
})();
```

And HTML :

```
<div class="col-md-2 product " ng-hide="product.soldOut" ng-repeat="product in products| orderBy:sortorder | filter: searchBox | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize | limitTo: pageSize">
    <img src="../products/{{product.image}}">
    <h4>{{product.nazwa}}
        <br>
        <br>
    </h4>
    <strong>{{product.cena| currency:"PLN "}}</strong>

    <div class="colored">{{product.usagee}}</div>
    <div class="buttons">
        <a href="/product/{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" style="">Szczegóły</a>
        <a href="/product/{{product.id}}" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" ng-show="product.dostepny">Kup</a>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-12">
    <uib-pagination class="pagination-sm" previous-text="Poprzednia" next-text="Następna" total-items='products.length' ng-model='currentPage' items-per-page='pageSize'></uib-pagination>
</div>
```

I was searching in google and stack but i can't find any good solution.

Comment: What happens is that the filter gets called before the data being returned from the server.

Comment: No, it's not duplicate...

Comment: It seems like products doesn't defined yet. Add a check in the filter that data is defined. Other way is to initialize products to empty array in the controller

Comment: @JacekJot it's not a duplicate, what happens is the product variable is not yet set before the filter gets called. You'll need to add a null-guard to the filter.

Comment: If i will put console.log(data); in to this filter i'm getting an arrays.

Comment: Working ! thanks a lot !

Comment: the filter should be called multiple times, the 1st time it's called the products is null.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check that $scope.products is defined it seems like it's undefined before the server returns its data.

You can set a check in the filter for data to be defined or initalize products in the controller to be an empty array.

Comment: It's working :)

I add 

if(data != null) {
                            return data.slice(start);
                        }