# AngularJS Pagination TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined

Tags: angularjs, pagination, angular-ui-bootstrap, slice

I am receiving an error message `TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined` while attempting to use Bootstrap Pagination. I believe the error is taking place due to a scope issue while attempting to apply the `.slice()` method on `items` in `ng-repeat`.

I have included the code where I believe the issue is occurring. I have been using this post - [AngularJS pagination and Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33584483/angularjs-pagination-and-cannot-read-property-slice-of-undefined) as a guide to resolving the problem I'm having.

Controllers.js:

```
defaultPage = angular.module('DefaultPage', ['ui.bootstrap']);

defaultPage.controller('DefaultController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.totalItems = $scope.ctrl.info.length;
            //console.log($scope.ctrl.info.length)
            $scope.itemsPerPage = 25;
            $scope.currentPage = 1;
            $scope.max = "3";

            $scope.pageCount = function () {
                var begin = (($scope.currentPage - 1) * $scope.itemsPerPage);
                //console.log(begin)
                var end = begin + $scope.itemsPerPage;
                //console.log(end)

                $scope.totalItems = $scope.items.slice(begin, end);
                console.log($scope.items)

            };
}]);
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="DefaultController as ctrl">
    <div class="search">
        <h1 class="shadow"></h1>
        <div class="searchbox">
            <i class="fa fa-search"></i>

            <input ng-model="query" placeholder="Search Issue Title or Case #" autofocus>
        </div>
    </div>

    <ul class="channellist">
        <li ng-repeat="items in ctrl.info | filter: query | filter: issue" class="channel cf">

            <a ng-href="#/issues/{{ctrl.info.indexOf(items)}}">
                <img ng-src="{{items.user.avatar_url}}" alt="channel logo for {{items.user.avatar_url}}" />

                <div class="info">

                    <h2 class="userName">{{items.user.login}}</h2>
                    <h4 class="case">case: #{{items.number}}</h4>
                    <h4 class="case">issue status: {{items.state}}</h4>
                    <div class="main">
                        <h3 class="title">{{items.title}}</h3>
                        <p class="body">{{items.body}}</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="label_info">
                        <ul>
                            <li class="mark">Created:</li>
                            <li class="mark"> {{items.created_at}}
                            </li>
                            <li class="mark">Updated:</li>
                            <li class="mark"> {{items.updated_at}}</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <uib-pagination boundary-links="true" max-size="max" items-per-page="itemsPerPage" total-items="totalItems" ng-model="currentPage" ng-change="pageChanged()"></uib-pagination>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Below link solved my issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723455/custom-filter-giving-cannot-read-property-slice-of-undefined-in-angularjs

Answer (score 0):

You can't slice something that does not exist, try to define items first.

Comment: I would like to slice 'items' from ng-repeat in my HTML. How can I do that? <ng-repeat="items in ctrl.info >

Comment: You could do an `ng-if` on the repeat and compare to the `$index` or you could implement a filter that takes a start and end argument and do the comparison that way

Comment: @paul147 I'm somewhat of a novice with Angular, I have created filters but I haven't use ng-if. I have look into uising a filter but I'm uncertain how i'd incorporate it with the ui-bootstrap paginate script i have in controller.js.

Comment: You should define items inside the scope. You are just saying to slice the items array but there isn't an array named $scope.items. The problem is inside your controller.